# calculating a fine and addtional fine java method error

Tags: java, methods

I have this problem I need to solve, I made a method to check if the parkingTime of a car is expired, here is the code

```
private boolean isParkingTimeExpired(ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter) {
    if(car.getNumberOfMinutesParked() > meter.getNumberOfPurchasedMinutes()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }     
}        

private double calculateFine(ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter) {
    double totalFine = 0;
    if(isParkingTimeExpired() == true) {
        totalFine = 20;
    }
}
```

I am told to make a method that will check if the parking time is expired and if so calculate the fine which is $20 per hour, and another $20 for every other additional hour. Now two things, when I try to call the method isParkingTimeExpired to check if time is expired it gives me an error saying method cannot be applied to given types, found no arguments, reason: actual and formal arguments differ in length. Why is this like that? I havent made much progress because I am lost trying to figure out the calculation and also why I cant call on the previous method. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are calling `isParkingTimeExpired()` but not passing it any arguments in your second if statement.

In your method signature for `isParkingTimeExpired` it is expecting a ParkedCar object and ParkingMeter object (see below).

`private boolean isParkingTimeExpired(ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter){`

In order to call it correctly, you must pass it the required arguments like this: `isParkingTimeExpired(car, meter);`

Comment: thank you for your answer, when I do that i run into an unexpected type error, required variable, found value :/

Comment: @onesnapthanos can you post your updated code and the exact error message please?

Comment: private double calculateFine(ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter){
    double totalFine = 0;
    
    if(isParkingTimeExpired(car,meter) = true){
            totalFine = ONE_HOUR_FINE_AMOUNT;
        }                                                                                                                     the error message popping up is as follows: i get an error underline below (car,meter) saying unexpected type, required: variable, found: value

Comment: @onesnapthanos it's because you used `=` instead of `==` which is for comparisons

Comment: @onesnapthanos no problem, everyone makes silly mistakes :)